# Why doesn't this PHP code to read number of messages in Inbox work?

Tags: php, email

It works on XAMPP but not on the host that serves my website (linux server). I do not see any error messages and the script just times out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Email Parser</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

echo "Hello World";

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}Inbox';
$username = 'abc@gmail.com'; //Replaced with actual user name and 
$password = 'abc';           //password in the script

$mbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
echo "+++++ <br>";
$MC = imap_check($mbox);

echo "***** <br>";
echo $MC->Nmsgs;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why the code snippet got truncated. It starts with <?php

Comment: You need to format it as a code sample. Use the preview before posting a question. I edited it.

Comment: If it times out it might be a firewall blocking outgoing port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you reach that host/port using other means from the server? Even though you can't do the SSL stuff by hand, you could try telnet (`telnet imap.gmail.com 993`) from the command line and see if that gets a connection. Possibly your server's firewalled off somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem. I contacted my hosting company to open the port for me and it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your host hasn't got the php_imap extention enabled

test that by doing:

```
var_dump(function_exists('imap_open')) ;
```

For your script to work the above should display 'bool(true)'. If bool(false) you've found the culprit.

Comment: The output shows bool(true). Thanks for the suggestion though.